# How do I clear controls in a previous load form after clicking command button in another form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have two forms: frm_Load and frm_Acct in Access db. Frm_Load is used to pull data into frm_Acct for processing daily transactions. After all the entries are completed in frm_Acct a button "cmd_Finish" in frm_Acct is pressed to finalize all the cash entries, and simultaneously closes frm_Acct while frm_Load remains open by design. The goal is to clear the data (without deleting data from the record source) in frm_Load after cmd_Finish in frm_Acct is pressed, this is to prepare for the next set of transactions in frm_Load.

I have tried the following two options:

```
Dim X As Control
For Each X In frm_Load
If TypeOf X Is TextBox Then
    X = Null
End If
Next X
```

and

`DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` (Which I am probably placing in the wrong "After Update" event of frm_Acct) How can I write and place this DoCmd in frm_Acct to clear controls in frm_Load?

I definitely appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I expect do not want the first code because that would remove data from record if controls are bound to fields. For GoToRecord, need to make sure frm_Load has focus. You don't show code closing frm_Acct. You have that line in AfterUpdate event of frm_Acct? Why not in cmd_Finish event?

Comment: Controls in frm_Load are "UNBOUND", and the code closing frm_Acct is 
 DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Acct".

Comment: So if those frm_Load controls are unbound and you want to discard any data they contain, wouldn't it be simpler to do `DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Load", acSaveNo` followed immediately by `DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Load"`